# Trying to configure and use redux toolkit and having trouble accessing state variables(Wierd stuff happening)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Trying to use redux toolkit for state management. I have the store and reducers all set up, and at first everything seemed to work fine. When I try accessing some of the state from a component all I get is 'undefined' BUT some state variables come through just fine so it is very confusing to me.

here is my store:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import productReducer from './productRedux';
import userReducer from './userRedux';
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  product: productReducer,
  user: userReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoreActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```

here is the userReducer:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    currentUser: 'TestUser',
    isLoading: false, //this can get accessed and console.logged just fine
    error: false,
    msg: false,
    random: 'hello', 
  },
  reducers: {
    loginStart: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.error = false;
    },
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
      state.msg = false;
    },
    loginFailure: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.currentUser = null;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  loginStart,
  loginSuccess,
  loginFailure,
  logout,
} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Here is where i try accessing and console.log the state var:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { AnalyticsCon } from './styles';

const Analytics = () => {
  const error = useSelector((state) => state.user.error);
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.user.isLoading);
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);

  console.log(error); //console logs just fine
  console.log(isLoading); //console logs just fine
  console.log(currentUser); //for some reason undefined but it is in the state

  return (
    <AnalyticsCon>
      <div>Analytics - view your store Analytics here</div>
    </AnalyticsCon>
  );
};

export default Analytics;
```

No matter how many variables I add to the state, I cannot access them in either reducer BUT I can access the ones that are there now. I do not understand this at all.

Comment: have you dispatched the login function? Cause might there is problem in   loginSuccess:   case

Comment: @WasifAli No, just trying to read the state right now, no actions

Comment: can you try logging the entire user object, also you can configure redux devtools ?and see if nothing is dispatched to be 100% sure ? as @WasifAli said there might be an action dispatching somewhere which you're not aware of ?